# Doob's Lp inequality on countable subset

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I'm reading a book that proves the following statement regarding Doob's Lp inequality:

> Let be $X_t \in L^p$ a continuous time martingale and $D$ some countable subset of $[0,\infty)$**. Then
>   $$P\Big(\sup_{s\in D\cap [0,t]}|X_s| \geq r \Big) \leq \frac{1}{r^p} E[|X_t|^p]$$

The way it's used in the book is $X_t$ is Brownian Motion:
$$P\Big(\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|X_s| \geq r \Big) \leq \frac{1}{r^p} E[|X_t|^p]$$
Which is to say, $\sup$ is on an uncountable set $[0,t]$. Here I note: $$\{s: \sup_{s\in D \cap [0,t]}|X_s| \geq r \} \subset \{s: \sup_{s\in [0,t]}|X_s| \geq r \}$$

So that: $$P\Big(\sup_{s\in D\cap [0,t]}|X_s| \geq r \Big) \leq P\Big(\sup_{s\in [0,t]}|X_s| \geq r \Big)$$

So is the highlighted statement still true for the way its used later in the book?

**Also, I think this is a typo, it should be $[0,t]$

Comment: Use the continuous hypothesis on the martingale to get that the two sups are equal

Comment: ah, this didn't occur to me. I can see schematically why this will work: any $r \in [0,t]\cap D^c$ needs to have an image $B_r$ that's $\epsilon$-close to its neighbors. Can you provide more detail to show the reverse inclusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subset $D$ should be dense in $[0,\infty)$. Then by path-continuity the supremum over $[0,t]$ equals to the supremum over $D\cap [0,t]$. This also guarantees that the supremum under question is measurable.

---

Taking an arbitrary countable subset does not make sense. For example, $t=2$ and $D=\{n^{-1}:n\ge 1\}$. $D$ is countable but it is clear that two suprema are different in this case.